# Calling a Java class from Adobe Air app

Tags: java, air

I have to develope a simple desktop application. I have to call my Jar behind it. I am thinking that I should have Adobe Air interface that will call my Jar.

Is it possible in Air. If yes, then I am going to learn Adobe Air, otherwise I will develope it in Swing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Air won't know what to do with the jar file.  If it was allowed Air could call java and pass it the jar (assuming java was installed), but I don't believe AIR apps have the capability to do system calls.

You're probably best off just sticking with Java, or replacing the jar with a flash library that accomplishes the same thing.  You really don't want to mix technologies if you can avoid it.

Comment: There is a new feature in AIR 2, called NativeProcess. You can use this to communicate with a jar-file for example. See [Interacting with a native process](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html) to learn more about this topic.

Answer (score 3):

I appreciate this is an old question, but you don't need to use Merapi.

Native processes are supported from Air 2.0 onwards.

See the API docs for the [NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) object.

Also, take a look at [this](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/invoke-native-process-in-adobe-air-2/) video, which demonstrates starting tomcat by invoking a jar.  So what Tahir Akram is asking is definitely possible now (although I don't think it was possible in 2009).

Answer (score 1):

I am new to AIR and I was also looking how to integrate AIR and JAVA , I found this website, which may be of  help

http://merapiproject.net/

Merapi is a technology that can be used as a messaging bridge between applications that run in the Adobe Flash player or Adobe AIR and applications written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can call your Jar files using NativeProcess. Like Python, you will need to create frozen binaries of your jar files into an .exe file.  I think JSMooth is a Java executable wrapper that converts jar to exe.

In fact, JSmooth will look for the JVM and if it's not installed, it will redirect user to fetch the download.

The nice thing with Python, you can bundle the python program in with your .py files with the help of py2exe.